# P-value in nnet: multinom() . P-value Wald test extracted, but ¿how i extract it by LIkehood ratio?

Tags: r, p-value, multinomial, mlogit

I got a multinomial model, which goes like this:

I got a bunch of observations (patients) that have 1 of 5 classes: Control, A_severe, A_low, B_severe, and B_low.

So I tried to fit a multinom model with the package nnet, and I extracted the Wald test p-values as follows:

```
multinom_wout20_1 = multinom(formula_wout20_base,data=wout_20_training, maxit=10000)
```

```
summary(multinom_wout20_1)
```

Coefs:

```
exp(coef(multinom_wout20_1))
```

Z Values

```
z_wout <- summary(multinom_wout20_1)$coefficients/summary(multinom_wout20_1)$standard.errors
z_wout
```

And we get the p-values:

```
# 2-tailed z test
p_wout <- (1 - pnorm(abs(z_wout), 0, 1)) * 2
p_wout
```

And then I passed them to a custom variable to see them as letters (more intuitive)

```
## Function to Pass our values to letters.
sign_levels_df_letter <- function(df) {
  df <- ifelse(df >.80, "Z", ifelse(df >.50, "FFF",
             ifelse( df >.30, "FF",
               ifelse(df >.10 , "F", 
               ifelse(df <= 0.0001, "AAA",
                      ifelse(df <= .0005,"AA+",
                             ifelse(df <= .001,"AA",
                                           ifelse(df <= .005, "A+",
                                                  ifelse (df<= .01, "A",
                                                            ifelse(df<= .05, "A-",
                                                                   ifelse(df <=.07, "B",
                                                                          ifelse(df <=.10, "C", NA
                                           
                                           ))))))))))))
                 
    
  return(df)
}
```

```
aux_pwout0 = sign_levels_df_letter(p_wout) ; aux_pwout0
```

Which I suppose is the same (cause they coincide its symbiology with *, ***, and **) if I use the package `stargazer`

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(multinom_wout20_1, type= "text" )   #   "html", out="multi1.htm")
```

But as seen in the response of this thread:

[multinomial logistic regression in R: multinom in nnet package result different from mlogit in mlogit package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42048872/multinomial-logistic-regression-in-r-multinom-in-nnet-package-result-different)

There is some problems with using Wald instead of LogLikehood.
**¿How can get the Likelihood Ratio test p-value from my model?**

I don't mind using other function for my data, but mlogit from the package mloget requires me to pass my data into a wide format, which is not as easy as it seems but I suppose I could extract from:

[R: how to format my data for multinomial logit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203540/r-how-to-format-my-data-for-multinomial-logit)

If some user of this last function could tell me if there is some secret function that automates this, that also solves my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Allright, i got it.

From this post i extracted a function to get the p-values of Likehood in nnet:multinom models, and i post it also as a response.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60835647/10465155

You can see it just below.

```
likehoodmultinom_p <- function(model_lmm) 
{

  i <- 1

  variables <-c("No funciona")
  values <- c("No funciona") 


  for (var in model_lmm$coefnames[-1]) { 

  variables[i] =paste(var)
  values[i]= lrtest(model_lmm, var)[[5]][2]
  i=i+1
   ## Contributed to stack at: 
  }
  return (data.frame(variables,values))
}
```